Retrieving firstName from a Firebase Realtime Database where UserId matches the uid of the person logged in
I have tried to figure this out using tutorials and videos and can't get it to work. My Firebase Realtime database has a table called "users". In the users table are two fields - UserId and firstName.
I want to retrieve the firstName field value of the record where UserId = uid of currently logged in user. Here is my code:
//monitoring authchanges 
onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    if (user) {
        const uid = user.uid;
        const firstname = await getFirstnameOfLoggedInUser();
        if (firstname) {
            welcomeTxt.textContent = "Welcome back, " + firstname + "!";
        } else {
            // Handle case where firstname retrieval fails (optional)
        }
    } else {
        console.log("user is logged out");
        welcomeTxt.textContent = "Welcome! Please sign in or create an account.";
    }
});

//get FirstName of person logged in
async function getFirstnameOfLoggedInUser() {
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    console.log(user);
    if (user) {
        const uid = user.uid;
        console.log(uid);
        const userRef = ref(database, "users/" + uid);
        console.log(userRef);
        get(userRef, (snapshot) => {
            const userdata = snapshot.val().firstName;

            console.log(userdata);
        });
    }
}

DB Structure (Values Changed for internet)
{ "users": { "-NuU3rpSGUXRSwQKrCJC": { "company": "CkCo", "email": "email@email.com", "firstName": "Frank", "lastName": "Rizzo", "userId": "77YntRQWh1d3y5pjfnhbRR17XkKWihsBG2" } } }
This code logs the current uid correctly but does not retrieve the correct record in the users table even though I see that the UserId and uid match. Please help!

Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your Firebase Console.

You'll need to use a query to get the user(s) with the correct first name based on their UID. Something like:
const usersRef = ref(database, "users");
const userQuery = query(usersRef, orderByChild("UserId"), equalTo(uid));
get(userQuery, (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
        const userdata = userSnapshot.val().firstName;

        console.log(userdata);
     });
});

Also see the Firebase documentation on ordering and filtering data.

Update: After the back and forth in the comments, I created this minimal repro where the query does work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebase-v9-rtdb-query-uid (check the console.log output)

Here's what I currently have: function getFirstNameForCurrentUser() {
const user = auth.currentUser;
if (user) {
const user = auth.currentUser;
const uid = user.uid;
console.log(uid);
const usersRef = ref(database, "users");
const userQuery = query(usersRef, orderByChild("UserId"), equalTo(uid));
get(userQuery, (snapshot) => {
snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
const userdata = userSnapshot.firstName.val();
    console.log(userdata);
  });
});

}
}

Still returns undefined. If I console.log the uid it displays the correct uid of the person logged in and the same value in the database. Here is the db structure:
{
"users": {
"-NuU3rpSGUXRSwQKrCJC": {
"company": "CkCo",
"email": "email@email.com",
"firstName": "Frank",
"lastName": "Rizzo",
"userId": "77YntRQWh1d3y5pjfnhbRR17XkKWihsBG2"
}
}
}
I changed the userId and values for the internet

That seems a casing difference. I used "UserId" in my answer, because that's what you have in your question. The JSON shows that you cased it "userId", so you should also use tht in the query: orderByChild("userId").

Awesome! Thanks for seeing that. Still returns "undefined"

Works for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebase-v9-rtdb-query-uid (check the console.log output)

copied your code and it worked! Always something small...thanks for your help! I owe you a beer
